# In a Cocoa Application for macOS, I save a bundle to disk using NSFileWrapper. How can I get the finder show the correct icon for my bundle?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In a Cocoa Application for macOS, I save a bundle to disk using NSFileWrapper. The Bundle is correctly saved and recognised as a bundle (Show package contents appear) but I cannot get the finder display the Icon I provide for the bundle. Here are my settings for the imported/exported UTIs:

[image]

Unfortunately, the bundle appears always with a blank file icon:

[image]

As you can see, the Finder recognises the file kind, but does not display an image for it. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the imported UTI. Imported UTIs are for document types that are **not** defined by your app. For example, if you were to write an app that works with Photoshop documents, you would import the UTI for those. Also, why is the exported UTI have "2" in its name/description? Finally, does your app bundle actually have an icon file named "Mbox" with an appropriate file extension (e.g. ".icns")?

Comment: Thanks a lot Ken. Unfortunately I have tried all of your suggestions with no luck.

Comment: I have a nearly identical configuration, except that I have always used `com.apple.package, public.archive` for **Conforms To**. Also, launch services is often very slow/lazy in updating application/document types in its database. At a minimum, open the window where your compiled application resides (Xcode > Products > Show In Finder) and launch it manually in the Finder. To be absolutely sure is does/doesn't work, [reset your launch services database](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7913794).

Comment: Thanks a lot James, that did succeed for me. You can add your answer, I will certainly approve it. It appears that it was due to public.archive not being set on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Exported UTIs** section, try setting **Conforms To** to `com.apple.package, public.archive`.

I'm no UTI expert, but that has always worked for my apps.